# Acumatica Kit Assembly Import Scenario

Tags: acumatica

I am working on an import scenario that creates kits. It is a simple set up. It takes the inventory ID, location, and quantity to add the kit; however, when I import them it gives me 2 locations instead of one. One location is automatically added to the kit assembly as a default and the other location that is specified in the file adds to the kit assembly as well. I want it to only show the location that I import. I do not want to show the default location. Is there a way to fix this issue? I have added some screenshots displaying the issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehMYT.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlVVw.jpg

Comment: You can add an action which will clear all Allocation lines which has quantity 0 and invoke it in the Import Scenario. I don't think that there is a way to clear that Allocation line without modification of the Kit Assembly entry.

Comment: Thanks, That is a big help.